# How to stream games from Xbox one to android phone

Tags: xbox-one, streaming

I want to be able to stream games from Xbox one to my phone so I can play destiny on-the-go. The perfect solution would be where I could stream it and somehow control it using my phone. However,  it would also be fine if I could just stream the game and then use a controller. Is this possible?

Comment: This, while perhaps technically feasible, is going to be all *sorts* of prohibitive when it comes to processor and bandwidth usage.

Comment: I basically want to use my phone as a TV screen for my xbox

Comment: Unless you have 300Mbps Internet access for your phone and your Xbox, you'll be limited to playing it within 20 meters of your Xbox.

Comment: so this is a terrible idea in real life, but theoretically you could get a video capture card to a pc to get your output from your xbox one into a pc which could then broadcast the video to wherever, then hook a custom gamepad emulator to the pc and xbox one to convert input, then build a interaction system from the phone to the pc. I'd estimate that at best you'd only have a few seconds of lag on every input-response loop. You could Loot Cave farm with that.

Comment: Video capture cards often have lag that can be measured in seconds.  They are not optimized for this case.

Comment: How would one play it within 20 meters of their Xbox? I just want to play Destiny upstairs when my Xbox is downstairs

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly help much in your current situation, but what you're asking for is pretty much exactly how PS4 Remote Play with the PS Vita works. So, uh, if you ever happen to find yourself in possession of those two devices, you'd be in luck! :/

Comment: You could stream your 360 or a second Xbox One to your Android or Iphone by running them through the T.v connection on the One. New update to Smartglass allows streaming to android and so on through the T.v app. Doing so willprobablyresultin the game feeling less responsive due to the video lag that will occur through the Xbox One alone. More streaming that to a phone.

Comment: @cloudymusic Does that mean it's possible on PS4?

Comment: @user65909 New answer there for you. Edited.

Comment: @Brok3n Not with a phone, but with a Vita, yes. (You can stream your PS4 console to your Vita either locally at home, or over the internet.)

Comment: Note that android phone can nativley support Xbox controllers, using on the go cable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the game streaming option in the Windows Xbox App to a PC to Windows 10 Remote Desktop on Android if you have Windows 10 Pro. Like Parsec, you will experience lag as the stream passes through an extra--and ultimately unnecessary--machine.

Yesterday Microsoft informed its customers that Windows Phones will be discontinued.  Hopefully now they will be inspired to deliver an in-house low latency solution allowing Xbox One content to be streamed directly to Android phones over a local network.

Answer (score -1):

You could try streaming your Xbox One (or any other HDMI devive, connected through the Xbox One HDMI Input) to your Android or Windows phone, using the SmartGlass app. With a new update, the SmartGlass app allows streaming to any Android or Windows phone. The game will probably feel less responsive, due to the video lag.

If you can accept a lag of about 10-40 seconds, I would suggest using Twitch.

Another option I could get working was video calling. Basically, I set Skype up on my tablet, and set it to face my TV using a $4 spider stand. When I call it from my phone, and answer it from my tablet, I have set up the tablet to display the television with Destiny running.

Streaming this way caused roughly 1.5 seconds of delay. This was acceptable for patrolling. I completed 5 patrols, and completed a public event in co-operation with other players, earning a gold medal. This was not ideal for PvP, however; playing Crucible, I went from a 1-1 Kill/Death ratio to 1-50. I would say the lag makes this unacceptable for any skill level.

Comment: Though, I am so doing this. Results later in the week. Enjoy.

Comment: In crucible, when heavy ammo arrived, got more lag, and as the game ended I got a screen freeze.

Comment: Tried to fix some minor inaccuracies (eg. you cant do this on apple), and generally clean up the answer (given it is the only correct one here, but was hard to make sense of). Are you saying that video calling is more ideal then streaming? I can get streaming to work a lot better then 1s lag, and I am confused how you would project the input over distance, to use the controller.

Answer (score -1):

you could get OneCast for iPhone...

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This post could use some more details, such as how to set it up, or your first-hand experience in using the app and how it performed.

Comment: Could also explain how an iPhone app will work on Android too!

Answer (score -1):

Parsec has worked super well with me high quality low latency and everything. Bluetooth xbox controller works 100 % with any device